# How to sort tab delimited out?

Tags: shell, ubuntu-10.04

In linux(Ubuntu), one shell utility will output the following data

```
23827492      name_1
3984989229      name 2
8238937      another name
```

so there are 2 fields, number and name. What I need is to sort this output by the numbers in asc or desc in linux shell. What is the easiest way without engaging python/perl?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sort -g <filename>
```

And use `-r` for reverse sort

Comment: does this do 'natural sorting'? i.e., will "100 a" come after "20 b" or will "20 b" be second because it starts with a 2?

Comment: check the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/sort.1.html)